# Is the analysis tool, "I Write Like" just for fun or is it legit?

Tags: fiction, style

I was curious because I submitted a few chapters and it analyzed my writing, and came back with I write like Anne Rice. I'm wondering if this is just a "for fun" analysis or if has some truth to it.

Comment: Have you read many Anne Rice books?

Comment: Yes, mostly in junior high school and high school. I haven't read any recently, so that was about 18 years ago.

Comment: Do you have a link to the wattpad function? I assume it is AI.

Comment: Here is the Story Insights report from Wattpad https://support.wattpad.com/hc/en-us/articles/360036219492-Story-Insights-Report-

Comment: And here's the I Write Like site. Anybody can input their text herehttps://iwl.me/

Comment: I entered some writings by me, then some by some of my friends, and finally the first chapter of Mein Kampf... all of them were Agatha Christie.

Comment: Then I put in a QuickSort implementation in C#, and got David Foster Wallace.

Answer (score 6):

### It's just for fun.

I copy/pasted a large chunk of my writing, and it told me I write like **Arthur Clark**. Then I copy/pasted a different large chunk from the same work (from the same scene actually), and it told me I write like **Dan Brown**.

It uses a very simple *machine learning* algorithm (I guess you could say an AI, but that is a stretch) comparable to a spam filter on email, that analyzed text from 50 different authors – the site does not say how much text.

At least one author **Margaret Mitchell** was removed because they decided the algorithm favored her too much, according to the author's github.

From the website's [About](https://iwl.me/about/) page:

> It’s a Bayesian classifier  ... I feed it with “Frankenstein” and tell
>   it, “This is Mary Shelley. Recognize works similar to this as Mary
>   Shelley.”   ... it takes into account more stylistic features of the
>   text, such as the number of words in sentences, the number of commas,
>   semicolons, and whether the sentence is a direct speech or a
>   quotation.

As a final test I copy/pasted 3 longish paragraphs from a different **Mary Shelley** novel *The Last Man*, and the site said it was **Charles Dickens**. I'll accept that the algorithm is detecting differences in the text, but it's debatable that it's detecting anything *stylistic* or *meaningful*.

Comment: As back up for this, I tried a section from Harry Potter (written by J.K. Rowling) and it gave me back Arthur Clarke. :P